# Storing products prices from multiple stores

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I'm working on a web service that will compare products prices from multiple stores.

I have the following database design in mind (simplified):

```
Store:
- id PK
- name
- url

Product:
- id PK
- name

ProductPricing:
- productUrl PK
- store
- price
- date
- discount
```

There's no ideal world, so products from different stores may vary /ex. a product name may be spelled differently or contains some other characters (ex. IV instead of 4)/. That's why I've decided to use an URL as a `Pricing` table primary key.

Pricings are grouped by product (there's a name and few more other attributes). When inserting a product pricing from the store API, there's a query checking if such product exist in database by name (after some string cleanup). If there's no such product, then new one is being created.

I'm wondering if this is the best approach? What if any store will change their URLs structure? Will such database design be efficient enough?

**Update**
@Gordon Linoff comes with a set of really good questions. Some answers and clarification can be found below.

What is the main attribute of the product within the application? Definitely product name. The key issue with storing product name as a primary key is a difference of the name across the stores /there's a internal service to fix those in the application, before inserting *new product*/.

The key functionality of the application is to identify different products across different stores. The second key feature is the connection between product and price/pricing history in multiple stores /that's why the URL as a primary key idea has born/.

*How will users look at the prices?*
Interesting question. There will be a product listing, with product names /and some other attributes/. In a single view, there'll be a list of prices across different stores. That's it.

From the other hand, products pricing will be updated once a day. If any URL will change, an application will try to inser a pricing based on a product name. If there's a database row /in a `Product` table/, the application will connect `Product` found with a new `Pricing` item. So the application should not suffer if any store will change their URL structure. Am I missing something?

Maybe should I just store an URL as a regular attribute /column in database instead of using it as a primary key/?

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

Using a remotely controlled URL as the primary key for a product seems like a really bad idea.  You have no control over the URL.  And, these things change not with a whimper but with a bang -- all of a sudden, all the URLs for a given site will change.

You need to change the perspective of the design.  How will *users* be looking at prices?  How will they be describing a product?  Is it important to identify exactly the same product across different sites?  These are the key attributes that you need to design around.

You may need to design your own infrastructure to identify products.  You may be able to use each vendor's scheme (these are often in terms of SKUs -- stock keeping units).  Or, you might have industry standard methods using something like UPCs (universal product codes).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Gordon! I've updated the original question to answer your questions. Maybe then, something comes to your mind :)